# WPF Metro Style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, microsoft-metro

I wanted to learn how to achieve Metro look for WPF.
I've seen Elysium, Mahapps, and others... But I wanted to learn how they were able to do integrate the look and style for Windows and controls... Is not only using styles right :). I'm not looking for creating a complete similar framework, but at least to understand how can I achieve similar results.

Perhaps you could give me come pointers where to start and what to search for.
Thank you.

Comment: Easy. You can see the code of mahapps for example and learn from them. You've got it [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use `Style` elements and custom `Control` classes in order to achieve the layout they have.

You can do the same by taking over full control of the `Style` of a `Window` for example by creating a general `Style` (one without `x:Key`, which is applied to all elements of the specified `TargetType`):

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            ..
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

On the `..` you can define the template for a `Window`, so you can add borders, labels, buttons, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually see how they do it on the Style Dictionaries that is added when you apply the themes. It's amazing how they use `Style` to achieve such awesome UI.

If you want, you can also directly install the theme using nugget package manager.

Here's an example

```
Install-Package Infragistics.Themes.MetroDark.Wpf
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask for free styles, he wants to know how they have achieved the layout.

Comment: I know, that's why I said that he can see how they did it by viewing the Style Dictionaries that is added when a theme is applied. Teaching OP how to use style won't give him much of an idea on what it's really capable of. One way to learn is by studying a complete theme.

Comment: What does your first line add then?